# Solution to specific surface integral involving a projection

Tags: calculus, integration, vector-analysis, stokes-theorem

I have an integral computation question:

Given the vector field $v = y \hat{z}$ I want to compute the surface integral $\int (\nabla \times v) \cdot da$ of the surface within the triangle with vertices $(a,0,0)$, $(0,2a,0)$ and $(0,0,a)$. The way I did it was to use Stokes Theorem and calculate the corresponding path integral $\int v \cdot dI$. The answer obtained was $a^2$ which as I understand is correct.

I am interested in the direct approach, in the literature I am using the solution is given simply as "$\nabla \times v = \hat{x}$ hence $\int (\nabla \times v)\cdot da$ is the projection of this surface on the $xy$ plane $= \frac{1}{2} \cdot a \cdot 2a = a^2$" Could someone provide some detail regarding this, this explanation does not seem clear to me. Thanks.

Comment: $\nabla\left(y\hat{z}\right) =\nabla\left(y\right)\times\hat{z} = \hat{x}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\,{#1}\,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,\mathrm{Li}}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> **Vertices**: $\ds{\vec{v}_{1} = a\,\hat{x}}$, $\ds{\vec{v}_{2} = 2a\,\hat{y}}$ and $\ds{\vec{v}_{3} = a\,\hat{z}}$. A unit vector perpendicular to the triangle is $\ds{\propto}$:

\begin{align}
\pars{\vec{v}_{1} - v_{2}}\times\pars{\vec{v}_{1} - v_{3}}
& = -\vec{v}_{1}\times\vec{v}_{3} - \vec{v}_{2}\times\vec{v}_{1} + \vec{v}_{2}\times\vec{v}_{3} =
\pars{-a^{2}\,\hat{y}} - \pars{-2a^{2}\,\hat{z}} + \pars{2a^{2}\,\hat{x}}
\end{align}
The unit vector is
$\ds{\hat{n} =
\color{#f00}{{2 \over 3}\,\hat{x}} - {1 \over 3}\,\hat{y} - {2 \over 3}\,\hat{z}
\propto \dd\vec{\mathbf{S}}}$. Then,
\begin{align}
\int\nabla\times\vec{\nu}\cdot\dd\vec{\mathbf{S}} & =
\int\hat{x}\cdot\dd\vec{\mathbf{S}} =
\int\verts{\dd\vec{\mathbf{S}}}
\verts{\cos\pars{\angle\pars{\hat{x},\dd\vec{\mathbf{S}}}}} =
\int\verts{\dd\vec{\mathbf{S}}}
{2/3 \over \verts{\hat{n}}\verts{\hat{x}}}
\\[3mm] & =
{2 \over 3}\,\times \overbrace{\mbox{Triangule Surface}}
^{\ds{\mathcal{A = {3 \over 2}\,a^{2}}}} = \color{#f00}{a^{2}}
\end{align}

---

> The triangle has sides of lengths $\ds{{\root{3} \over 2}\,a}$, $\ds{\root{2} a}$ and $\ds{{\root{3} \over 2}\,a}$ such that
>   $\ds{\mathcal{A} = {3 \over 2}\,a^{2}}$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just want to confirm my understanding of the integral of $\int d\vec{S}$. If say we were integrating $\int d\vec{S}$ of a hemishere bowl of radius $R$. Would the following be correct: $\int d\vec{S} = R^2 \int_{0}^{2 \pi}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin \theta d \theta d \phi \hat{r} = 2 \pi R^2 \hat{r}$?

Comment: @JohnDoe You are welcome. Thanks.